# What's the best way to send 100 emails using SendGrid, each email has different CC and BCC

Tags: c#, sendgrid

SendGrid has the capability to send to multiple recipients with one call to its SMTP API by adding 'To' recipients in X-SMTPAPI Header : http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html.

You can customize the body of the email for each recipient using substitutions:
http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html

But I can't find a way to send customized CC and BCC for each recipient. 
I want to send different CC and BCC addresses for each email. How to do that?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to customize a CC or BCC through the X-SMTPAPI header on a per message basis.  You could however, assign a BCC or CC that would apply to all the emails you're sending.

So for example, if you're sending out something that looks like this:

```
"x-SMTPAPI": {
  "to": ["user1@example.com", "user2@example.com", ...],
  "bcc": ["some.employee1@example.com", "some.employee2@example.com"],
  ...
}
```

Both user1@example.com and user2@example.com would receive emails and some.employee1@example.com and some.employee2@example.com would be BCC'ed on both emails that went out.